# $2^n + 3^n = x^p$ has no solutions over the natural numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

A few weeks ago, I was asked to prove that $2^n + 3^n = x^2$ has no solutions over the positive integers. My proof was:

$2^n + 3^n \equiv (-1)^n \equiv \pm 1 \mod{3}\\\text{However, quadratic residue mod 3 is always 0 or 1. Therefore:}\\n = 2m\\\text{Now, working mod 5:}\\2^{2m} + 3^{2m} \equiv 4^m + 9^m \equiv 2 \times(-1)^m \equiv \pm 2 \mod{5}\\\text{However, quadratic residue mod 5 is }0, \pm 1\\\text{As such, } 2^n + 3^n \text{ is never a perfect square.}$

Naturally, I questioned if the $2^n+ 3^n$ is ever a perfect cube, which a friend and I managed to prove was false, by working mod 7 and mod 9, and using Fermat's Last Theorem. This led us to consider the equation $2^n + 3^n = x^p,\,(n,x,p)\in \mathbb{N}^3,\,p\geq2$ and conjectured that there are no solutions. Obviously, if $p$ is composite and there are no solutions for any one of its factors then there are no solutions for p (e.g. $p = 4$ has no solutions because $x^4 = (x^2)^2$, so it is only necessary to consider the cases where $p$ is prime.

$p = 5$ was next, and we managed to partially prove it by working mod 11 and 25, and again, Fermat's Last Theorem, leaving only the case $n\equiv 6 \mod{10}$.

So my question is: is $2^n + 3^n$ ever a perfect power, and if not, how can this statement be proved? Alternatively, if this statement is false, are there any strategies other than using a computer to find a counterexample?

Comment: [Conjecturally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tijdeman%E2%80%93Zagier_conjecture), there are no solutions. Of course, I understand you want an unconditional proof, just pointing out that this follows from standard conjecture.

Comment: I think that a proof of this claim is currently out of reach. The claim is correct for $n\le 10^5$.

Comment: @Wojowu it's interesting to see most of the work done on this conjecture has been setting the exponents and varying A, B and C, which is almost the opposite of what is done here.

Comment: @Peter That could very well be true. The thing is, every particular p doesn't seem too difficult to prove - the strategy is to find p-residues (is that the right term?) mod a certain number to reduce the cases left for n, until the last case leads to a contradiction.

Comment: I arrived at $n=4\cdot 10^5$. Still no solutions.

Comment: @Peter Of course you won't find a solution, because otherwise you would've solved [Tijdeman-Zagier Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tijdeman%E2%80%93Zagier_conjecture) and would've won $1,000,000, which is unlikely.

Comment: You are right. I would not have such luck ...

Comment: But I am astonished about the awards for such number-theoretical problems.

Comment: This equation has no solutions. The proof of this fact, however, is not easy, as far as I know (it appears as a special case of a somewhat more general result in a paper of mine with Nicolas Billerey to appear in Math. Comp.). Our proof relies upon Frey curves.

Comment: @user236182 This is not true,because this a special case of the conjecture and maybe can be solved(maybe)

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas It's useless for him to search for a solution, because he won't find one. If he'd found a solution, then he would've solved [Tijdeman-Zagier conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tijdeman%E2%80%93Zagier_conjecture) (by proving it is false) and won a lot of money. A huge amount of numbers have been checked to solve the conjecture without success.

Comment: @MikeBennett That sounds very promising. Would you mind sharing what is the general result you prove in the paper, or do you want to keep it secret until the publication?

Comment: An old version of this paper is available on the arxiv : http://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07922.pdf

Comment: @MikeBennett Wow, thank you very much! Feel free to post that as an answer, I'll accept it if no one finds a simpler proof for this specific case within the next few days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll provide a (relatively) simple proof (with the hard work hidden!) tailored for this problem - a similar argument works for more general equations such as, for example,
$$
2^m \pm 3^n = x^p.
$$
Suppose we have a solution to the equation
$$
2^n+3^n=x^p,
$$
where $n$ and $x$ are positive integers and $p$ is prime. Then, as noted by the proposer, we may, through congruence arguments, assume that $p \geq 5$. We may also suppose that $n \geq 5$. Consider the "Frey" curves
$$
E_1 \; \; : Y^2 = X (X-3^n) (X+2^n),
$$
if $n$ is odd, and
$$
E_2 \; \; : Y^2 = X (X+x^p) (X+2^n),
$$
if $n$ is even (we consider these two cases separately to get the smallest conductor we can). Then it can be shown (by Tate's algorithm) that each curve has conductor
$$
N_{E_i} = 6 \prod_{q \mid x} q,
$$
where the product is over prime $q$. Since we suppose that $p \geq 5$ (which guarantees that certain Galois representations that I haven't defined are irreducible), we may appeal to Ribet's level lowering results to conclude that these Frey curves correspond to certain weight $2$ modular forms of level $6$. This is a contradiction since the space of such forms turns out to be empty.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you very much! It leaves enough to go learn more yet still clearly outlines the proof, (although it's definitely a bit beyond me right now)!